# When to use $p\times (1-p)\times n^2$ for variance?

Tags: variance

I was always taught to use $p\times(1-p)\times n$ for binomial variance. In a textbook for actuarial problems, I have:

```
probability of       death benefit

A .01                200,000

B .05                100,000
```

Using

$Var(A) = .01\times 200000^2 - (.01\times 200000)^2 = 396000000$

I get the same answer with binomial formula when I square the $n$: $.01\times .99\times 200000^2 = 396000000$

Using
$Var(B) = .05\times 100000^2 - (.05\times 100,000)^2 = 475000000$

I get the same answer with binomial formula when I square the $n$: $.05\times .95\times 100,000^2 = 396000000$

---

But, I don't understand why I should square the $200000$ and $100000$. Isn't the formula for binomial variance: $p\times (1-p)\times n$

Comment: The numbers 200000 and 100000 are "benefits". Maybe Dollars, or Euros. In your example, they calculate with $n=1$, so they look at the variance of benefit that 1 (dead) person gets. So you have a random variable $X$ that can be 0 or 1, depending on the event death. That one has variance $Var(X)=p\cdot(1-p)\cdot 1$. But for the total benefit $B=b\cdot X$, where $b=100000$, the variance is $Var(B)=b^2 Var(X)$.

Comment: the difference is that the money is all on a single trial vs multiple *independent* trials (for your n formula). the n^2 formula is perfect correlation between trials/people (which insurers hope never happen)

Comment: $.05\times .95 \times 100,000^2=475000000$ not $396000000$

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the variance of a binomial random variable.
In your example, the number of deaths would be modelled as a binomial variable. In the example of your textbook, the quantity of interests is however not the number of deaths, but apparently the benefit payed for one particular person in one year. This is either 0 or 100000 / 200000, depending on the incident.

Consider the random variable $X$ that is $X=0$ if the person does not get the benefit, or $X=1$ otherwise (which is bad for that person...). $X$ has a binomial distribution with $n=1$, thus $\mathrm{Var}(X)=1\cdot p\cdot(1-p)$.

The benefit itself, $B = b\cdot X$, has variance
$\mathrm{Var}(B) = b^2 \mathrm{Var}(X) = b^2\, p(1-p)$.

Answer (score 0):

The squared terms do probably not refer to the parameter $n$ in a binomial distribution. Instead your computation* and the formula with a square relates to a scaled [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) with support $x \in \lbrace 0, w \rbrace$.

This has variance $w^2\cdot p(1-p)$. The square term originates from a scaling which increases the variance with the square of that scaling. See '[Variance: Addition and multiplication by a constant](https://Variance#Addition_and_multiplication_by_a_constant)'.

---

*The computation is using the rule $\text{Var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$

Comment: Sidenote: For the binomial distribution, you get a variance $n \cdot p(1-p)$. This also relates to the Bernoulli distribution, since the binomial distribution can be seen as the sum of $n$ independent and identical distributed (iid) Bernoulli variables. When you sum $n$ iid variables then the variance scales by $n$, when you multiply a variable by $n$, then the variance scales by $n^2$. That is why your variables $A$ and $B$ have a formula for the variance that is similar to the formula for the binomial distribution.